# Create Accounts Using Web3.js in Browser

Tags: web3js, transactions, addresses

TL;DR - Replicated Ethereum Blockchain. Running Local Node. Connecting Local Node to Web3.js in browser using RPC. Want to create addresses & send transactions

Details -

I have a blockchain that is forked from Ethereum. Thus all its functionalities are almost similar if not same. Before building a wallet for my blockchain, I'm trying to develop a wallet for Ethereum that works in the browser using web3.js.
I am not well versed with Node.js and hence want to use the browser version of web3.js

Having imported web3.js (version 0.20.6) from [web3.min.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/dist/web3.min.js), I can view the web3 object in the console window. I can even use various functions such as `web3.sha3` and web3.isConnected.

I can view the `web3.personal.newAccounts()` function and when I use it as web3.personal.newAccounts("passphrase"), it returns `personal_newAccounts` function is not available/does not exist

On trying to use `web3.eth.accounts.create()`, it tells me this function does not exist as the version I'm using is 0.x and version 1 stable release is not out yet.

How can I create addresses for my private blockchain local node and if possible send transactions using web3.js browser.

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer not fully solves the problem, but can solve a similar problem which i have already faced.

I get error response during calling *admin.web3Sha3(hexData).send()* from Spring boot using ***web3j***

> "The method web3_sha3 does not exist/is not available"

I have checked the method in geth console and found it works

> `>web3.sha3("0x536f6d6520415343494920737472696e6720746f20626520686173686564",{encoding:'hex'}) "0xb21dbc7a5eb6042d91f8f584af266f1a512ac89520f43562c6c1e37eab6eb0c4"`

Actually there is a problem when I have started the geth node.

I have started with *--rpcapi "eth,net,**web2**,personal,miner"*

which should be *--rpcapi "eth,net,**web3**,personal,miner"*

Hope someone like me get help from this.